# How load JSON file into external table

Tags: json, plsql, oracle12c, handsontable, external-tables

We had an old framework which reads the data from external table and processes it. Now I want to use the same but this time I will get data from Handsontable Json. Here I want to do it in a bulk insert into external table so that it's easy for me to use the existing framework.

```
FROM json_table(p_transaction,
    '$.massARData[*]'
    COLUMNS(sysName PATH '$.sysName',
            erpTaxCode PATH '$.erpTaxCode',
            taxengTaxCode PATH '$.taxengTaxCode',
            txnDate PATH '$.txnDate',
            taxPointDate PATH '$.taxPointDate
```

Comment: You can't insert into an external table. The task is going to be to write to the file, using [`utl_file`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm) if you're driving this from the db.

Comment: An oldie but goodie: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=425